Forming a cubic polynomial with sum of pair of roots as roots. Broken.
Today I found something weird,
I don't think there is a careless mistake in my steps, yet I also cant believe this loop hole.
Btw. note this is not a homework question, the question I am asking came from a bigger question, and numerical value is chosen by me for example explanation.
Question
Given the cubic equation $ x^3 - 3.5x + 1 = 0 $ with roots $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma $, we are asked to find the cubic polynomial whose roots are $ \alpha + \beta, \beta + \gamma, \gamma + \alpha $.
#Answer
Step 1: Using Vieta's Formulas
From the given cubic equation $ x^3 - 3.5x + 1 = 0 $, we can apply Vieta’s relations to extract information about the sums and products of the roots $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma $:

$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0 $
$ \alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha = -3.5 $
$ \alpha\beta\gamma = -1 $

Step 2: New Roots
We are now concerned with the roots $ \alpha + \beta, \beta + \gamma, \gamma + \alpha $.
Let:

$ p = \alpha + \beta $
$ q = \beta + \gamma $
$ r = \gamma + \alpha $

We know that:

$ p + q + r = 2(\alpha + \beta + \gamma) = 0 $, so $ p + q + r = 0 $
We also need to find expressions for $ pq + qr + rp $ and $ pqr $.

Step 3: Sum of Products of the New Roots
The sum of the products of the new roots $ pq + qr + rp $ can be found as:
$$
pq + qr + rp = (\alpha + \beta)(\beta + \gamma) + (\beta + \gamma)(\gamma + \alpha) + (\gamma + \alpha)(\alpha + \beta)
$$
Expanding each term:
$$
= (\alpha + \beta)(\beta + \gamma) + (\beta + \gamma)(\gamma + \alpha) + (\gamma + \alpha)(\alpha + \beta)
= 2(\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha) + (\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2)
$$
Using the identity $ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^2 - 2(\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha) $, and knowing $ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0 $, we get:
$$
\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 = -2(\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha) = -2(-3.5) = 7
$$
Thus:
$$
pq + qr + rp = 2(-3.5) + 7 = -7 + 7 = 0
$$
Step 4: Product of the New Roots
The product of the new roots $ pqr $ is:
$$
pqr = (\alpha + \beta)(\beta + \gamma)(\gamma + \alpha)
$$
Expanding this product:
$$
pqr = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma)(\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha) - \alpha\beta\gamma = 0 \cdot (-3.5) - (-1) = 1
$$
Step 5: Forming the New Cubic Polynomial
The new cubic polynomial with roots $ \alpha + \beta, \beta + \gamma, \gamma + \alpha $ is given by:
$$
x^3 - (p + q + r)x^2 + (pq + qr + rp)x - pqr
$$
Substituting the values we found:
$$
x^3 - 0x^2 + 0x - 1 = x^3 - 1
$$
Thus, the cubic polynomial is:
$$
x^3 - 1 = 0
$$
The problem:
But see!, initial equation $ x^3 - 3.5x + 1 = 0 $ whose roots all are real and around $-2,0.292893,1.70711$ (wolfram alpha)
And solution says $x^3 - 1 = 0$ is the cubic with sum of pair of roots as roots. Whoah, we know it is famous polynomial with roots as $1,\omega, \omega^2$ two of which are complex. How can that be sum of two real numbers??
P.S: Yes, I used chatgpt so I don't need to type latex and stuff, yet I verified,and it matches with my notebook.

$(\alpha + \beta)(\beta + \gamma) + (\beta + \gamma)(\gamma + \alpha) + (\gamma + \alpha)(\alpha + \beta)
= 2(\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha) + (\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2)$ - I think you may want to double-check this.

omg, right,thanks math cant go wrong (i was tempted to use a+b+c whole square and wrote 2 instead of 3)

Since the sum of the roots is $0$ you only need to find the new cubic whose roots are $-\gamma, -\beta$ and $ -\alpha$

and that turns out to be same polynomial! thank you people. I am feeling bad to post a question with careless error on this site, should i delete?

Not quite the same: it should be $x^3 - 3.5 x - 1$ instead of $x^3 - 3.5 x + 1$.
